# Why is gunicorn displaying an extra process?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn web server on my django app in my docker container and my gunicorn config is:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8001'
loglevel = 'debug'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
preload = True
reload = True
workers = 2
```

My gunicorn command is:

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py project.wsgi:application
```

I am expecting it to only show **2** processes when I hit `ps aux` in the container or `docker top` but it turns out that it has three like the one below

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.1  21756  2600 ?        Ss   21:48   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
root         6  0.0  1.0  97424 21860 ?        S    21:48   0:01 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py project.wsgi:application
root        11  2.7  3.2 310404 65560 ?        Sl   21:48   1:20 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py project.wsgi:application
root        12  2.7  3.2 310408 65572 ?        Sl   21:48   1:20 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py project.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gunicorn has [master](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html) process that handles/spawns workers so that is why you see 3 processes ( master and 2 workers )

Comment: Is the master worker pre-defined and something that I can not control?

Comment: I have linked you a document regarding master process signals, what exactly do you mean regarding controlling it ( it is part of  how gunicorn works )

Comment: Does a master also handles HTTP request? Or does it also have a worker type?

Comment: No master process as stated in documentation handles just spawning of worker processes ( see name difference )